# Why am I able to import a Bootstrap component in React with a different name?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

This is what I mean:

```
import BsssButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";
```

This works the same way as:

```
import ButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";
```

..and I don't understand why?

The `BsssButtonGroup` is not an existing or defined componend in the ButtonGroup component in React Bootstrap, so how am I able to import it? WHAT is being imported exactly? How does writing some random name work?? I thought you have to import the exported component? But `BsssButtonGroup`  is not exported, so how am I able to import it then?

Also, what happens when I pass props to this component? Where are these props handled, and how can I access them?

Answer (score 0):

In ECMA Script, there exist to kinds of exports in modules. `default` and named. In React, default exports are the rule, in Angular, e.g., named exports are preferred.

You can export an identifier (e.g. class) as a named export like this:

```
export class MyClass {}
```

You import it like this:

```
import { MyClass } from 'mymodule';
```

You can change the name of the imported identifier with this syntax:

```
import { MyClass as MyClassAlias } from 'mymodule';
```

In contrast, you can make an identifier the default export of a module like this:

```
class MyClass {}

export default MyClass;
```

A module can have at most one default export.

The import syntax is slightly different for the default export (you omit the curly braces):

```
import MyClass from 'mymodule';
```

Note that in that case `MyClass` is just a name you give the default export of `mymodule` when importing it.
You could also have picked any other name and use that in the importing module.
This allows you to refer to it in the module where you imported it using that name.
This is why your code works just fine with the `BsssButtonGroup` import.

You can find more info on ECMAScript exports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify something. Did you mean to say that `myClass` is just a name you give the default export FROM `mymodule`? Basically because a component can have only 1 default export, importing without braces from that component automatically means you are importing the default export, so any name reference works?

Comment: Also, do you know what happens when I pass props to a component? Like when I import a component, let's say `ButtonGroup`, and then I pass props to it. Where are these props handled? Is it something I can handle, or is it something React Bootstrap handles?

Comment: To the first question: yes, I meant it that way. I updated my answer to make that clearer. Any name will work as a reference in the importing module.

To the second question: props are always handled by the component that receives them. They are the most direct way to pass data from one component to a child component. Since this question is not directly related to ES modules, but rather React specific, I'd encourage you to create a new question.

Comment: I just submitted a new question. Can you please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73634815/what-happens-to-the-props-that-i-pass-to-a-react-bootstrap-component